# Static files on public folder not working Next.JS 13

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js

I am new on Next, and was trying to load static images on a project, but they are not loading.

I followed this tutorial https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/optimizing/images#local-images and my code is something like this

layout.jsx

```
import Image from 'next/image'

import flutterImg from '../public/logo-flutter-png.png'

export default function RootLayout ({ children }) {
  console.log(flutterImg)
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body>
        <Image src={flutterImg} width={500} height={500} alt='Flutter Logo' />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

page.jsx

```
export default function HomePage () {
  return (
    <h1>Probando</h1>
  )
}
```

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    loader: 'akamai',
    path: '/'
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

The console.log() of flutterImg prints this:

```
{
src: '/_next/static/media/logo-flutter-png.ba0c3334.png',
height: 500,
width: 500,
blurDataURL: '/\_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Flogo-flutter-png.ba0c3334.png&w=8&q=70',
blurWidth: 8,
blurHeight: 8
}
```

I also tried setting {flutterImg.src} in src in the Image component, but it did not work either.

My next version is 13.3.0. If you need more information please just ask, thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to load the static images. I used the img label, and in src I set the path of the image ignoring /public.
Following the example above:

```
export default function RootLayout ({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body>
        <img src="logo-flutter-png.png" alt='Flutter Logo' />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just cut off the public string from the url, works for me.